# How can I figure out if my motherboard support High Density RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard

I've been reading for some time what the reason is that most of DDR2 rams are labeled "works on AMD only".

I figured out that reason is that most of these "cheap" RAM modules are high density, which are supported only by few intel chipsets.

Is there a way to figure out whether my motherboard support this or not, before I buy it? My board is http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2960

Here are some links to discussions I read:

http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/why-is-this-ddr2-amd-only.114684/

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/user-support/ram-upgrades-watch-for-high-and-low-density-requirements/

Comment: What CPU do you have?  What specific density are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

To be positive, you would need to contact Gigabyte.

To be called DDR2 Ram, the ram chip needs to have an SPD chip containing JEDEC information which identifies the RAM Module to Bios.

They also will contain extended information. 
On Intel it's called XMB and on AMD chipsets it's called EPP.
If the PC Bios doesn't understand EPP or XMP it will fallback to the JEDEC info.

So theoretically, even if it's extended info is not compatible, it should fallback to JEDEC and at least boot up.

But, it's no guarantee because of memory timings, another complication; i.e. CL4 RAM in a "CL6 only" motherboard.